# Joining two tables by index?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to merge an original Postgres table with another table that has the same number of rows (I got this table by making API requests from the original table).

Row orders of Table 1, 2, 3 must be the same!

Is there any way that I can join these two tables using index? (Orders of these rows are essentially the same).

Two tables don't have any matching value.

For example,

> Table 1 (50,000 rows) (a, b, c columns)
>
> Table 2 (50,000 rows) (d, e, f columns)
>
> Desired output: Table 3 (50,000 rows) (a, b, c, d, e, f columns)

Comment: What do you mean by "index"?

Comment: Index as in a position of each row. Two tables have the same order of row positions so I just wanted to merge them together by "index".

Comment: So you basically just want to put them side by side/combine them and retain the original row order of each source table?

Comment: Yes! I want to retain the original row order of both Table 1 and 2. And create a Table 3 with the SAME row order.

Comment: Is there anything about each table at the moment that you can ORDER BY in order to restore the original order after doing a select on them? Because if you select from a table without specifying an order, the results could be returned to you in any order.

Comment: Rows in a relational database do not have "an index" or "a position". There is no such thing as the "original row order" in a table of a relational database

Comment: Unfortunately there is no column that I can ORDER BY and preserve the row order...

Comment: so how exactly did you expect this problem to solve if you dont have an index to work with? I mean what makes you so sure that any row in either tables match together, if you understand what i mean? What exactly makes these columns of rows of tables match together?

Comment: Unless you have column you can use to order, it's not possible.

Comment: Guys, ROW_NUMBER () OVER () worked as you can see the answer below. It's NOT impossible!

Comment: It may *seem* to work, but the order is undefined, so the maching of pairs is in fact random. (hint: update one or more records, and the matching will probably change)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do:

```
with sample_data as (
        select 1 as id, 'aa'::text as val
        union all
        select 2 as id, 'bb'::text as val
        union all
        select 3 as id, 'cc'::text as val
),
sample_data2 as (
        select 4 as id, 'dd'::text as val
        union all
        select 5 as id, 'ee'::text as val
        union all
        select 6 as id, 'ff'::text as val
)
, sd_rn as (
        select id
                , val
                , row_number() over (order by id) rn
        from sample_data
)
, sd2_rn as (
        select id
                , val
                , row_number() over (order by id) rn
        from sample_data2
)
select *
from sd_rn s1
join sd2_rn s2 on s1.rn = s2.rn
```

First two CTEs are just to generate two sample tables.

I'm not sure what do you mean by index, but you will need to have some sort of unique identifier for each row, so you can go with row_number() as shown above.
Also, sql does not guarantee any ordering, so make sure you specify it also.
Then you just join on the row number generated by the window function.

The method above will work with any number of columns.

Comment: thanks for the comment. But I think the problem with your query is that if I order by "a" column in Table 1 and "d" column in Table 2, it will mess up the result.

Comment: @ShaneKim Given what you've posted in the comments on your question, the concept in this answer is your best bet. But try this slightly different version: `WITH t1 AS (SELECT a, b, c, ROW_NUMBER() OVER () AS rn FROM table1), t2 AS (SELECT d, e, f, ROW_NUMBER() OVER () AS rn FROM table2) SELECT a, b, c, d, e, f FROM t1 JOIN t2 USING (rn) ORDER BY rn`